# How to get GitLab to trigger TFS 2015 Build

Tags: git, tfs, gitlab, tfsbuild

My code is currently located in a GitLab repository. I have a TFS 2015 Build definition configured to pull the code from an external git repository and build the code. This works fine if I manually load the TFS web page and select queue build.

What I would like to do is have GitLab push an event to TFS to queue the build automatically. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Are you using the old XAML builds or build v.next?

Comment: Task based build definitions

Answer (score 0):

TFS is capable of [integrating with service hooks](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/service-hooks/get-started), the service hooks enable you to perform tasks on other services when events happen in your TFS projects. But on TFS side, there is no such service that have GitLab push an event to TFS to queue the build automatically by default.

TFS provides [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build) to queue a build, you can check whether GitLab side supports using the api:

```
POST https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version={version}
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. I have looked at the TFS REST API and it doesn't support the post from GitLab push events so I would have to create a translation service between the 2 services.

Comment: kindly share your solution once you achieve creating a translation service between the 2 services.

Answer (score 0):

You can create webhooks in GitLab and then create a webapp to track the webhooks and trigger the TFS build via API.

Comment: I've written the service and I am tweaking it now under a few projects but that's essentially what I'm doing. I created a REST web service for web hooks to push the JSON request to and then I translate that data to queue a TFS Build definition.

Comment: Could you share the service code somewhere? @JoshDeLong